# Cursor is exhausted after aggregation

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I try to get list of `buildings` which an `user` belong to by this `aggregate` query:

```
const approvedBuildings = await BuildingMembersModel.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      user: userId,
      status: ACCEPTED,
    },
  },
]).cursor({ async: true }).exec();

const data = [];
approvedBuildings.eachAsync((err, member) => {
  data.push({
    _id: member.building,
  });
});
```

But it always throw this error:

`UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: cursor is exhausted`.

So what is the cause of this error and how can I fix it? Thank you in advance!